# find docker containers created using a docker image

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

how to find which docker container is using/referencing a particular image?

To give more detail, say I have some 10 docker images and there are some 30 docker containers.. How can find which containers are created using docker image ID XXXXX using a simple command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dig through the `docker history` output for other images to see what is linked back. There's an image out there that automates much of this that you can run with the following:

```
 docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
   nate/dockviz images -t -l
```

More details on the above command can be found on [this github repo](https://github.com/justone/dockviz).

Comment: docker does not have any in built command to find this information instead of using a external image? @bmitch

Comment: `docker history` or `docker inspect` and a lot of digging or scripting. Otherwise, no, I'm not aware of any other built in command to find this.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
`docker ps -a | awk '{ print $1,$2 }' | grep $(docker images | grep *image-id* | awk '{ print $1}')`